# Can we display Cost, Clicks and Impression all together in a 2-D graph?

Tags: user-research, user-centered-design, ux-designer, dashboard

I feel cost is a different metric than clicks and impressions. How do I show this for multiple channels say fb, instagram, youtube etc all together? Please help.

Comment: What message are you trying to convey with the graph?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as such it is a better to be asked at Cross Validated SE (https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. You need a graph with 2 Y axes. One Y axis can represent 'number' for clicks and the other 'cost'

You can get creative and use multiple colors for different types of data.

Here is an example, and I would like to emphasise that ofcourse it's just an example.
[image]

Comment: sensational user name!!!